# Issue in XML File paring using XMLSerDe in Hive

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

Below is my input XML

```
 <entity>
  <link idType="ProviderId">AEY000977645</link>
  <link idType="PAID">000977645</link>
  <link idType="PID">AEY</link>
  <message reason="Not Currently In TMS Database" status="Unmappable"/>
 </entity>
```

I need to parse this data and create a Hive table using hivexmlserde with 4 columns(ProviderID,PAID,PID,message_reason). Since all the values are inside the  tag it's difficult to parse the data. Below is my table DDL.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE xml_testing
(
         provider_id    String,
         paid           String,
         pid            String,
         message_reason String
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.provider_id"="/entity/link/@idType", --> not sure what to give here  
"column.xpath.paid"="/entity/link/@idType", --> not sure what to give here  
"column.xpath.pid"="/entity/link/@idType", --> not sure what to give here
"column.xpath.message_reason"="/entity/message/@reason"  
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/input/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<entity>",
"xmlinput.end"="</entity>"
);
```

can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: Rather having three columns defined why not define a column as map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select Element by attribute value.

ie /entity/link[@idType='ProviderId']/text()

```
        CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE xml_testing
        (
                 provider_id    String,
                 paid           String,
                 pid            String,
                 message_reason String
        )
        ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
        "column.xpath.provider_id"="/entity/link[@idType='ProviderId']/text()",  
        "column.xpath.paid"="/entity/link[@idType='PAID']/text()",   
        "column.xpath.pid"="/entity/link[@idType='PID']/text()", 
        "column.xpath.message_reason"="/entity/message/@reason"  
        )
        STORED AS
        INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
        OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
        LOCATION '/input/'
        TBLPROPERTIES (
        "xmlinput.start"="<entity>",
        "xmlinput.end"="</entity>"
        );
```